# How to create custom alt codes or modify existing ones?

Tags: windows, unicode, special-characters, codepages, typesetting

As said in the title, I have the need of typing symbols like greek letters and math symbols often. My most common use of these symbols is in plain text.
In systems like mine (spanish is the system language), existing alt codes some times don't work well. For instance alt + 227, which would have to generate pi symbol, doesn't. Instead it productes Ò. This is upsetting.
I tried to learn Unicode codification of these symbols for using them by typing alt + Numpad+ + Unicode of symbol.
This palliates the problem a bit but of course unicode numbers are difficult to remember. It would be better if there would be a solution by mixing the confort of alt with something like what julialang does: \pi → π.
Is something like that possible? Is it possible to custom alt code numbers for reallocating symbols?

Note1: I'm using Windows 10.

Note2: I've changed my system language because changing my codepage (which was 850) by typing chcp 437 in cmd did not work. Now when the change was made chcp page is by default 437. Currently I'm using alt codes using this code page.